# Overview for SQL-familiar person moving to Cassandra/NoSQL

Tags: cassandra, nosql

After years of dealing with relational DBs, I am quite <del>comfortable</del> <del>brainwashed into</del> normalized into thinking about tables, columns and rows.  Cassandra is still eluding my mind fully wrapping around it.

I understand its more of persisting maps, and you can only query on the unique keys for those maps, but my understanding is incomplete.

Yes, I am RTFM.  Still, can someone give me a nice, concise description of how Cassandra structures data vs. a SQL db?  I mean, 1000 foot view, how it works differently?

For instance, at the Ebay tech blog, it says:

> Don’t think of a relational table.
>
> Instead, think of a nested, sorted map data structure.
> Source: http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/

And I almost get it fully... but not quite.

---

These are some great answers.  Added a bounty to see if it inspires anyone to make an even more authoritative response.

Comment: For ref, I think you must have read Jay Patels blogpost http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: As the original question was about Cassandra, that will be the focus of this answer.  While Cassandra and other non-relational (NoSQL) datastores often do share similar concepts, it cannot be assumed that the ideas detailed here will work with other non-relational datastores.

The best way to go about this, is to remember that it is standard practice (for Cassandra) to build your data model to suit your queries.  The main difference, is that RDBMS tables are built with efficient *storage* of the data as the main focus.  In the Cassandra (non-relational) world, the main focus changes to how you want your queries to look.  Often, that may translate to storing the same, redundant data keyed multiple ways...and that's ok.  This is explained in the DataStax doc [Comparing the Cassandra Data Model to a Relational Database](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/ddl/about-data-model#comparing-the-cassandra-data-model-to-a-relational-database).

Let's say that I have the following user table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    username TEXT,
    firstname TEXT,
    lastname TEXT,
    phone TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (username));
```

After inserting some sample data, that table looks like this:

```
username  | firstname | lastname | phone
------------------------------------------------
mreynolds | Malcolm   | Reynolds | 111-555-1234
jcobb     | Jayne     | Cobb     | 111-555-3464
sbook     | Derial    | Book     | 111-555-2349
stam      | Simon     | Tam      | 111-555-8899
```

The `users` table will allow me to query my users by `username`, as that is our PRIMARY KEY.  But what if we wanted to query that data by phone number?  You may be tempted to add a secondary index on `phone`, but the cardinality of `phone` would probably be just as high as `username`.  The proper way to solve this, is to create a new table to allow you to query by phone.  Note: This model assumes that `username` and `phone` are both unique.

```
CREATE TABLE usersbyphone (
    phone TEXT,
    username TEXT,
    firstname TEXT,
    lastname TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (phone));
```

Let's assume that our next entries are for the users "Hoban Washburne" and "Zoe Washburne."  As they are married, they will have the same (home) phone number.  Cassandra will not allow entries to share a primary key, and will overwrite (with the last entry winning).  So we'll need to change the primary key on our `usersbyphone` table, like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (phone,username));
```

Here `phone` is our partitioning key (key that determines the partition where this row is stored) and `username` is our clustering key (key that determines our on-disk sort order).  Using these two together in a composite primary key will ensure uniqueness.  This will allow us to select our `usersbyphone` table like this:

```
SELECT username, firstname, lastnamea, phone FROM usersbyphone;

username  | firstname | lastname | phone
------------------------------------------------
hwashburne| Hoban     | Washburne| 111-555-1212
jcobb     | Jayne     | Cobb     | 111-555-3464
mreynolds | Malcolm   | Reynolds | 111-555-1234
sbook     | Derial    | Book     | 111-555-2349
stam      | Simon     | Tam      | 111-555-8899
zwashburne| Zoe       | Washburne| 111-555-1212
```

It is important to note, that the `usersbyphone` table does not *replace* the `users` table...it works in conjunction *with* it.  You will have some queries on that data set which need to be served by the `users` table, and some that will need to be served by the `usersbyphone` table.  The downside is that keeping the two tables in-sync is done outside the database, typically by your application code.  This is one example showing how your thinking must differ in the non-relational paradigm.

As DataStax MVP John Berryman explains ([Understanding How CQL3 Maps To Cassandra’s Internal Data Structure](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure/)), under the hood, Casssandra will store our `users` data in a structure that looks something like this:

```
RowKey:mreynolds
=> (column=, value=, timestamp=1374546754299000)
=> (column=firstname, value=Malcolm, timestamp=1374546754299000)
=> (column=lastname, value=Reynolds, timestamp=1374546754299000)
=> (column=phone, value=111-555-1234, timestamp=1374546754299000)
------------------------------------------------------
RowKey:hwashburne
=> (column=, value=, timestamp=1374546757815000)
=> (column=firstname, value=Hoban, timestamp=1374546757815000)
=> (column=lastname, value=Washburne, timestamp=1374546757815000)
=> (column=phone, value=111-555-1212, timestamp=1374546757815000)
------------------------------------------------------
RowKey:zwashburne
=> (column=, value=, timestamp=1374546761055000)
=> (column=firstname, value=Zoe, timestamp=1374546761055000)
=> (column=lastname, value=Washburne, timestamp=1374546761055000)
=> (column=phone, value=111-555-1212, timestamp=1374546761055000)
```

The Map-of-a-Map concept (mentioned in the eBay article) definitely comes into play here.  Our `usersbyphone` table  will look a little different from our `users` table:

```
RowKey:111-555-1234
=> (column=mreynolds, value=, timestamp=1374546754299000)
=> (column=mreynolds:firstname, value=Malcolm, timestamp=1374546754299000)
=> (column=mreynolds:lastname, value=Reynolds, timestamp=1374546754299000)
------------------------------------------------------
RowKey:111-555-1212
=> (column=hwashburne, value=, timestamp=1374546757815000)
=> (column=hwashburne:firstname, value=Hoban, timestamp=1374546757815000)
=> (column=hwashburne:lastname, value=Washburne, timestamp=1374546757815000)
=> (column=zwashburne, value=, timestamp=1374546761055000)
=> (column=zwashburne:firstname, value=Zoe, timestamp=1374546761055000)
=> (column=zwashburne:lastname, value=Washburne, timestamp=1374546761055000)
```

Due to the primary key structure, notice how Wash (hwashburne) and Zoe (zwashburne) are technically stored in the same row.  This structure allows us to quickly query all users who share the same phone number.

In summary:

- Tables (column families) are to be used in the most efficient way to *query* the data.  RDBMSs encourage the use of normalization to most efficiently *store* the data.
- With composite keys, Cassandra groups similar data together in nearby rows.
- Cassandra takes advantage of on-disk (clustering) sort order to optimize operations.
- Cassandra primary keys are always unique.  Different writes to data with the same primary key will overwrite each other (last write wins).
- CQL (Cassandra Query Language) is a limited subset of SQL.  While CQL provides those coming from a RDBMS background with familiar syntax, it is important to remember that many SQL keywords and concepts are not present in CQL.

Comment: Awesome answer, care to add more for a bounty? :)

Comment: @mtyson I have plans to, but I keep having to put out fires here at work...ugh. I'll add more tonight. Promise.

Comment: Bah,  work! :)  Looking forward to the extra details.

Comment: *Very* enlightening and informative, thanks!  The examples really nailed it.

Answer (score 2):

With a relational DB you define columns and every row has those columns (to oversimplify).

With Cassandra (and HBase, for that matter), each row has its own columns which are expressed as name/value pairs.  Each row has a row key, too.

You may decide that each row will have the same column names (called a "static model") and that would mimic how data is stored in a relational database.  Or you could have a dynamic, or "wide row" model in which the column names are not necessarily the same from row to row.  In this latter model, column names could be timestamps, for example, with the corresponding values being tweets, transactions or weather metrics.  You could go wild and implement any other structure you desire, as long as you keep it to a row key and column name/value pairs for each row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've got a bounty on the question if you feel like adding more details!

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of differences. Will try to help a bit:

- SQL DBs mostly rely on B-tree data structure. So you define a data schema with columns, sizes and RDBMS performs look-ups/updates of your data in place. It is much easier to organize automated indexing with such kind of data structures.
  Here is basic description of B-tree in MySQL: http://guptavikas.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/b-tree-index-in-mysql/
- Cassandra's record may be spread among disk/SSD. Each column may be physically located quite far from others in the same record. It makes Cassandra possible to have a tremendous write speed. When new data arrives it just writes it to the end of file (simplified). In case of updates the old data is marked using tombstones and keeps disk space until compaction which does not happen very often. SQL databases in most cases try to re-write existing record on the same physical place by utilizing disk space more effectively.

Additionally Cassandra is designed for high scalability and work in multi-node cluster, but it is different story. Here you will find more about Cassandra's internal data structures and more: http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/a-deep-dive-into-understanding-apache-cassandra

Due to structural differences there are cases where SQL/Cassandra may be better/worse to each other e.g:

- Adding a new column to SQL table schema (big table on prod, which is heavily used) is often quite hard operation. With Cassandra it is very lightweight
- Cassandra has limited support for transactions, it is concentrated around a single row. With SQL DB you have very powerful transactional mechanisms.
- Data access by secondary index is limited in Cassandra, no joins, no multi-table queries.
- With Cassandra it is easy to get rid of SPOF (single-point of failure) since it has built-in replication without master. With SQL databases you often have a kind of Master-Slave replication where Master is SPOF. The solutions of  Master-Master in SQL world are quite hard, and have own problems. It is much easier to implement scalable, highly available systems with limited Cassandra operations. SQL DB is much more powerful in terms of data handling functionality, while it has own cost.
- and more..

Comment: Thanks, care to add more for a bounty? :)